# How is that word-logi riddle called?

Tags: puzzle-identification

A few years ago, when I was a child, I really liked that one logic puzzle. I tried to google it but couldn't found a puzzle or name of the puzzle.

It uses a grid similar to a crossword grid, in which you have to fill in words. These words are given and sorted by the length of the word. The goal is to find the correct position of a word, based on its length and the position of the letters that share a cell.

What is this puzzle called?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're describing a "Criss-Cross" or "Fill-In" puzzle.

Examples can be found [here](http://www.puzzlechoice.com/cw/CrissX_Arcx.html)